# Is there any free Lidar dataset available?

Tags: data-request

I need a lidar-captured dataset to test my pointcloud model with that. Is there any free available lidar dataset?

Answer (score 0):

[Open Topography](https://portal.opentopography.org/dataCatalog) is a great resource for free aerial lidar and photogrammetric point clouds. At the time of writing, the USA and New Zealand seem to have the greatest coverage.

[NOAA](https://www.coast.noaa.gov/dataviewer/#/lidar/search/) is probably the best source of freely available bathymetric lidar.

Most national & regional governments undertake periodic lidar surveys for applications such as flood modelling and forest mensuration. This data is often made available upon request. For example, the [US National Lidar Dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Lidar_Dataset_(United_States)) has data for each state/county. Other nations are also developing [National Lidar Datasets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_lidar_dataset).

To the best of my knowledge, there are currently two satellite lidar platforms providing free data:

1. NASA GEDI: a full-waveform lidar covering the tropics and mid-latitudes.
2. NASA IceSAT-2: a photon-counting lidar with global coverage.

Comment: Washington State DNR LiDAR Portal.